# Propagation delay and its measurement in datasheet

Tags: datasheet, mosfet-driver, delay, gate-driving

[image: Propogation delay]I am referring to Gate driver [LM5102](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm5102.pdf)

Here the terms are bit misleading

1] Lower turn off propagation delay

2] Turn on delay

[image]

[image]

But application curves uses different measurements symbols(tp/tdl)/names,
I am now assuming turn on delay is  50% of VI to 10% output

Propagation delay is 50% of input to 50% of output
Is this right but application curves speaks differently

How is it measured ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turn OFF time**
When in Figure 17 signal HI turns off / goes from high to low **(HI falling)** the output HO also goes from high to low **(HO falling)**.
The time it takes for this "HI falling to HO falling" is the Higher (input to output) Turn-**Off** Propagation Delay \$t_{HPHL}\$ as defined in chapter 6.6.
In Figure 17 this delay is shown with the symbol/name \$t_P\$. (So, \$t_P = t_{HPHL}\$.)

When in Figure 17 signal  LI turns off / goes from high to low (LI falling) LO also follows (LO falling). The time it takes for this "LI falling to LO falling" is (as expected) the Lower Turn-**Off** Propagation Delay \$t_{LPHL}\$ as defined in chapter 6.6.

Note that it has the same value as *Higher* Turn-Off Propagation Delay.
In Figure 17 this delay is therefore shown with the same symbol/name \$t_P\$. (So, \$t_P = t_{LPHL}\$ = t_{HPHL}\$.)

**Turn ON time**
When in Figure 17 signal LI turns on / goes from low to high, LO follows, but with quite a delay.
The same applies when in Figure 17 signal HI turns on / goes from low to high: HO follows with quite a delay.

With RT1 and RT2 you can change thid **turn on** delay.
There will be a turn-**on** propagation delay from input to output just as there is when turning off. However, there is an aditional time delay caused by RT1 and RT2, resp called time delay \$t_{RT1}\$ and \$t_{RT2}\$. There sum is resp. \$t_{DH}\$ and \$t_{DL}\$ as shown in Figure 17.

These parameters \$t_{DL}\$ and \$t_{DH}\$ have been defined in chapter 6.5, section time *delay controls* as well as in Figure **13**. (Last sentence of page 12 of DS should refer to Fig 13 not to Fig 18.)

**Summary**
*How long takes it for the output to follow the input **when turning off**?*
The Turn-Off Propagation Delay \$t_P = t_{HPHL} = t_{LPHL}\$.

*How long takes it for the output to follow the input **when turning on**?*
It is determined by the values of RT1 and RT2. Check Figure 13 for the total delay time \$t_{DH}\$ and \$t_{DL}\$.

Comment: This is what i understood from this neat explanation from output curves [1]while turning off only delay it should notice is 27ns [2] While turning on you mentioned it as total delay , Is it not tp+ RT1 delay i.e 27ns +(resistor oriented delay)? And figure mentions only RT(resistors) delay?

Comment: The values given for \$t_{DH}\$ and \$t_{DL}\$ in chapter 6.5, section time delay controls **are the same** as in Figure 13. So, therefore, Figure 13 shows \$t_{DH}\$ and \$t_{DL}\$. There are no values given in the datasheet for  \$t_{RT1}\$ and \$t_{RT2}\$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is non-overlapping logic which alters the rising edge delays. This non-overlap timing prevents both drivers from being on at the same time. The Rt pins set this delay.

The falling edge delay is made as short as possible, for the same reason.